# NullPointerException occuring when creating new instance for JAXBContext

Tags: java, jaxb

I got Null pointer exception when creating the instance of JAXBContext for unmarshalling.
The below line is inside a function, which will be called each time when I upload a XML which needs to be unmarshalled.

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance("com.foo.bar");
```

After sometime it is started throwing NullPointerException.The exception itself is not clear. Please let me know if any of you come across this scenario.

Exception trace:

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(Unknown Source)
```

I am using JDK 1.6.0_18 version. And for JAXB also I am using the JDK which has JAXB in it.

Regards,
Sakthi. S

Comment: 'Unknown Source' looks suspicious, looks like some libraries are missing.

Comment: Are you running your application in an application server or OSGi environment?  Also since `JAXBContext` is thread safe you only need to create it once and then create an `Unmarshaller` per operation.

Comment: @blaise .. Thanks.. I also think of creating JAXBContext once, will do that. And this piece of code will be running inside a jar file on a Unix/Linux server. The xml content will be passed to it. And this error is not coming initially. It was working fine for sometime. And after that only it is started throwing NullPointerException

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the package "com.foo.bar" is not accessible. Have you tried something like:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBCOntext.newInstance(MyClass.class);
```

If this compiles, you know you have it in your classpath.

Comment: Thanks John for your reply. the package was accessible. And it was working for quite sometime. But suddenly it started throwing this exception. I suspect this could be Threading issue. Since I am creating this context for every call.